# Using CSS to remove overlapped div after 5 seconds

Tags: css

My page has an overlapped div, which it will be hided after 5 seconds. However, I realize that the buttons behind the div cannot be pressed due to the div is still there after 5 seconds.

To remove the div, I have tried with `display:none` but it does not work.

Here are my css:

```
.ox-messages {
    -webkit-animation: seconds 1.0s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation: seconds 1.0s forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 5s;
    position: relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes seconds {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -9999px;
    //display: none;
  }
}
@keyframes seconds {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -9999px; 
    //display: none;
  }
}
```

The problem looks like this:

[image]

The alert messages (in green) are overlapping the buttons (the note-plus icon).

Please help and thanks.

EDIT: I change `position:relative` to `position:absolute`, which it does not block the buttons but the messages stack together.

Comment: can you share a complete code ? so we can also see the buttons and the issue

Comment: Sorry I can't share the complete html code. I will paste a screenshot.

Comment: `display: none` should've worked. Consider declaring `pointer-events: none` on the hidden element in question. Or declaring a `position` property on your buttons so that you can leverage the stacking context by applying a `z-index` property to them.

Comment: `Sorry I can't share the complete html code.` we are sorry too but we cannot help with a screenshot

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look.

Comment: All that is required is a Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable Example to demonstrate the issue, and preferably in an embedded StackOverflow code snippet for *user-friendly reproduction and troubleshooting*, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I tried `position:absolute`. It does not block the buttons now but the messages stack together. What should I do for the messages div?

Answer (score 1):

Please feel free to copy and paste this code in any html editor (or press code snippet below) and you will see that the JavaScript function will indeed remove the div.  In this example, no text will be displayed in the website, because we removed the div in which the text is contained by using JavaScript:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 
<div id="div_we_want_to_remove">
    <!-- We will not see the following text on the webpage if we execute the the JavaScript code that I included -->
    <p1> It is possible to get rid of this text using javascript</p1>
</div>
<script>
//this is the JavaScript code that's needed to get rid of that div
function remove_div() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('div_we_want_to_remove');
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    return false;
}
//remove_div literally will remove the div
remove_div();

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried with jQuery but for some reason it does not meet my goal. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Hey Brian, you actually won't need jQuery.  I updated my code, please feel free to copy and paste this code in any html editor.  The Javascript code in this code will remove the div that surrounds text, thus preventing the text from appearing on a website.

Comment: Also, making a div hidden using display:none won't get rid of the div, it only makes it hidden. The JavaScript function will do the job.

Answer (score -1):

you can set `pointer-events: none;` on that div when you hide it, and it won't get in the way anymore

Answer (score -1):

Set the `visibility: hidden` then the element will be hidden from the document. Making the button behind it clickable.

```css
.ox-messages {
    -webkit-animation: seconds 1.0s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation: seconds 1.0s forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 5s;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes seconds {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
@keyframes seconds {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>TEST</button>
<div class="ox-messages"></div>
```

Comment: Nope it does not remove the div but hide.

Comment: You can't remove the div with CSS. Even with `display: none` it won't be removed. So either use `JavaScript` or `jQuery`.